# Where is my menu editor

Tags: menus

So I've opened up a WordPress site I've developed some time ago where I've never had to use the menu editor. Problem is, I do need it now, but it doesn't show up in the wp-admin 'Appearance' section. I've checked my `functions.php` but there's nothing in there that instructs to hide it. I've searched Google for an answer but menu-plugins are kind of in the way for good doc results.

Is it hidden by default nowadays? How can I make it to show up?

Answer (score 2):

I've asked this question a bit to early, but to help others in the feature here's the solution.

For the menu editor to appear, you need to register a menu first:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_header_menu' );

function register_header_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
```

Or as pointed out by Howdy_McGee:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

Comment: You don't necessarily *have to* register a Menu. Using the same hook you could just tell your theme to support menus: [`add_theme_support( 'menus' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support)

Comment: You are right, but how would one get a created menu? If a menu is named 'Main Menu', can I get it like this: `$loc = get_nav_menu_locations(); wp_get_nav_menu_object( $loc['main-menu'])`?

Comment: You could use the menu widget

Comment: @Tim 100% of the time I use [`wp_nav_menu( 'Menu Name' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to get / display my menus, but looking at the codex on the function you want to use: [`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object) it says you can also pass in just the name: `Header Menu` to get the object back.